# Magento2 : Missing Public Hash for payment information?

Tags: magento2, payment, braintree

I've a site which uses Braintree with the Vault enabled. The cards appear to save correctly but no public hash is passed in the `additional_data` array when attempting to use it on the frontend. Below is an example of the code passed:

```
additional_data: {public_hash: "", payment_method_nonce: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", is_active_payment_token_enabler: true}
```

This then returns the error:

```
{"message":"An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again."}
```

The Magento version is 2.2.2 (enterprise), though I'm not in control of patches I can't say how up to date it is. How can I correct this missing public hash?

Comment: Having the same issue on Magento open source 2.4.3. Anyone have a solution?